# How does making an MVC controller action asynchronous improve performance?

Tags: performance, asynchronous, model-view-controller

Our development manager is keen that we use the async versions of LINQ methods where possible, and then the whole method returns a Task, and we propagate this up to the action which also returns a Task.

How does this improve the performance of an MVC web application?